# Add straight line beneath a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to add straight lines beneath a scatter plot for instance in order to delimit the region where |y| < x and |y| < 2 * x.
I wrote something similar to th code below which give satisfactory result but requires to know the range of the data beforehand.
I would like to make a template for this graphics that would work equally well if the maximum abscissa is 1e12 or 0.1.
I could replace the 1 and .5 in my code by huge numbers but I am sure there is some neater way to achieve this result.

One constraint is that the straight lines should be *beneath* the marks of the scatter plot.

My current code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \tikzset{bisector/.style={black}}
    \tikzset{half bisector/.style={black, dashed}}

    \coordinate (origin) at (axis cs:0,0);
    \draw[bisector] (origin)--(axis cs:1,1);
    \draw[bisector] (origin)--(axis cs:1,-1);
    \draw[half bisector] (origin)--(axis cs:1,.5);
    \draw[half bisector] (origin)--(axis cs:1,-.5);

    \addplot[only marks] table[x=x, y=y] {
      x y
      .3 .7
      .2 .1
      .5 .6
      0.4 -0.5
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Its output:

[image: sample output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the fact that PGFPlots stores the axis limits in the keys `/pgfplots/xmin` and `/pgfplots/xmax`: You can draw the lines using

```
\draw (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin})
    -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax});
```

Defined like this, the lines will always go from one edge of the plot to the other. It's a bit tedious to type, so it's probably a good idea to define a command like

```
\newcommand{\straightline}[2][]{%
    \draw[#1] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},#2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin})
        -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},#2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax});
}
```

Then you can draw the lines by simply putting

```
\straightline[half bisector]{0.5}
```

in your code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\straightline}[2][]{%
    \draw[#1] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},#2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin})
        -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},#2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax});
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \tikzset{bisector/.style={black}}
    \tikzset{half bisector/.style={black, dashed}}

    \addplot[only marks, red] table[x=x, y=y] {
      x y
      .3 .7
      .2 .1
      .5 .6
      2.4 -2.5
    };

 \straightline{1}
 \straightline{-1}
 \straightline[half bisector]{0.5}
 \straightline[half bisector]{-0.5}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot compile your example.  I get the following error message :

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '1*-2.00134e-2' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near '*-2.00134e-2'..

Any idea of what is causing it?

Comment: @AlfredM.: is that using my code, or did you make any changes?

Comment: Using your code.

Comment: @AlfredM.: What version of PGFPlots are you using?

Comment: pgfplots.sty    2011/12/29 v1.5.1 (git show 1.5.1-4-g53e640f )
    tikz.sty    2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)
     pgf.sty    2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)

Comment: The problem was indeed caused by too old a version.

Answer (score 4):

You can save your data in a table using `\pgfplotstableread`, then with the `\findmax` command you find the maximum value of `x` (`x` because the second argument of `\findmax` is `0`, with `1` you find the maximum `y`) and finally you use this maximum value stored in the macro `\max` to draw your bisectors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\findmax}[2]{
    \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={#2},sort cmp={float >}]{\sorted}{#1}%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{#2}\of{\sorted}%
    \let\max=\pgfplotsretval%
}

\pgfplotstableread{
.3 .7
.2 .1
.5 .6
0.4 -0.5
3.0 1.2
}\data

\begin{document}
\findmax{\data}{0}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=0]
    \tikzset{bisector/.style={black}}
    \tikzset{half bisector/.style={black, dashed}}

    \coordinate (origin) at (axis cs:0,0);
    \draw[bisector] (origin)--(axis cs:\max*2,\max*2);
    \draw[bisector] (origin)--(axis cs:\max*2,\max*-2);
    \draw[half bisector] (origin)--(axis cs:\max*2,\max);
    \draw[half bisector] (origin)--(axis cs:\max*2,-\max);

    \addplot[only marks] table[x index=0, y index=1] {\data};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I also have trouble compiling your example.  The error message is 

! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '3.0*2' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near '*2'..

Comment: @AlfredM. I think it is because you are using an old version of `pgfplots`.. updating it both my answers and @Jake's one will compile

Comment: The problem was indeed caused by too old a version.